# Java Spark takes a long time to create a session

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

I am switching from python pandas to Java Spark for data analytics and new to it. In my project I'm not using hadoop, just fetching data from mysql db.

The code is like this:

```
List<QtStkDailyRehabilitation> qtStkDailyRehabilitations = qtStkDailyRehabilitationSelfMapper.getStockDailyKData(stockCode);
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("sparkTest").config("spark.master","local")
        .getOrCreate();
StructField field1 = DataTypes.createStructField("date", DataTypes.DateType, false);
StructField field2 = DataTypes.createStructField("close", DataTypes.FloatType, false);
StructType stockInfo = DataTypes.createStructType(Lists.newArrayList(field1, field2));
...
```

So I didn't install a hadoop on my computer. But I found when I create a SparkSession, it takes a long time - around 20 seconds, and it comes out with a warning.

The log shows below:

```
2020-05-26 18:45:02.507 DEBUG 15880 --- [nio-8031-exec-1] c.e.d.q.d.Q.getStockDailyKData           : ==>  Preparing: SELECT * FROM qt_stk_daily_rehabilitation WHERE (stock_code='002241') ORDER BY trade_date DESC 
2020-05-26 18:45:02.520 DEBUG 15880 --- [nio-8031-exec-1] c.e.d.q.d.Q.getStockDailyKData           : ==> Parameters: 
2020-05-26 18:45:02.873 DEBUG 15880 --- [nio-8031-exec-1] c.e.d.q.d.Q.getStockDailyKData           : <==      Total: 2921
2020-05-26 18:45:12.199  INFO 15880 --- [nio-8031-exec-1] org.apache.spark.SparkContext            : Running Spark version 2.4.3
2020-05-26 18:45:21.335  WARN 15880 --- [nio-8031-exec-1] org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader  : Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2020-05-26 18:45:21.406  INFO 15880 --- [nio-8031-exec-1] org.apache.spark.SparkContext            : Submitted application: sparkTest
2020-05-26 18:45:21.456  INFO 15880 --- [nio-8031-exec-1] org.apache.spark.SecurityManager         : Changing view acls to: edz
```

As you can see. `Running Spark version 2.4.3` shows 10s after sql returns results, and then after 9s it prints a warning about hadoop.

Following codes works ok and I can use DataFrame to calculate, but every time I run into this session create code it will take 20s. I guess it tries to access hadoop server which I don't have one. Is it normal and how to make it faster? Or can I disable hadoop for now just to enjoy it's MLlib features?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. the Warning is fine. You just don't have Hadoop native libraries. For most of your work it will mean nothing. 2. It takes 12 seconds for my spark-shell to fully start so I don't think it is that long.

Comment: You can change org.apache.spark logging level to DEBUG in spark's `log4j.properties` to see how much stuff is going on in these 10 seconds :)

Comment: @SašaZejnilović, thanks then i'll ignore this.